# Click and drag to edit value in React/js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to click on one of these controls and drag up and down to edit the value:

[image]

I instantiate the components like this:

```
    <div className="flexbox-column">
        <Location id="foo" bars="5" beats="1" divisions="1" enabled={envelope && !envelope.locked} onEdit={(args: any) => {handleEditStart(args)}}/>
        <Location id="bar" bars="5" beats="1" divisions="1" enabled={envelope && !envelope.locked} onEdit={(index: number, offset: number) => {handleEditLength(index, offset)}}/>
    </div>
```

I listen for mouse down like this:

> window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown)

But same event fires for every component on the entire page, and with coordinates relative to whatever component the user clicked on. So I can't tell which one the user clicked on. This is the output from one click on any component on the page:

```
location.handleMouseDown(foo): e.offsetY 11 
start foo e.offsetY 11 
mouse down - dragItemIndex 1 e.offsetY 11 
location.handleMouseDown(bar): e.offsetY 11 
start bar e.offsetY 11 
mouse down - dragItemIndex 1 e.offsetY 11
```

My component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from "react"
import "./location.css"

export const Location = (props: any) => {

    const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [lastMouseY, setLastMouseY] = useState<number>(0)
    const mouseDownRef = useRef(mouseDown)
    const lastMouseYRef = useRef(lastMouseY)
    const [dragItemIndex, setDragItemIndex] = useState<number>(0)
    const dragItemIndexRef = useRef(dragItemIndex)

    const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const handleMouseDown = (e: any) => {
        if (!divRef.current) {
            return
        }

        console.log(`location.handleMouseDown(${props.id}): e.offsetY ${e.offsetY}`)

        if (e.offsetY >= 0 && e.offsetY <= divRef.current.clientHeight) {
            console.log(`start ${props.id} e.offsetY ${e.offsetY}`)
            setLastMouseY(e.offsetY)
            e.stopPropagation()
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp)
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
            setMouseDown(true)
            setLastMouseY(e.offsetY)

            var dragItemIndex = 1
            if (divRef.current) {
                const clientLeft = divRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().left
                const offsetX = e.clientX - clientLeft
                if (offsetX < divRef.current.clientWidth / 3) {
                    dragItemIndex = 0
                } else if (offsetX > (divRef.current.clientWidth * 2 / 3)) {
                    dragItemIndex = 2
                }
            }

            console.log(`mouse down - dragItemIndex ${dragItemIndex} e.offsetY ${e.offsetY}`)
            setDragItemIndex(dragItemIndex)
        }
    }

    const handleMouseUp = (e: any) => {
        setMouseDown(false)
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp)
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
        e.stopPropagation()
    }

    const handleMouseMove = (e: any) => {
        const distanceY = lastMouseYRef.current - e.offsetY;
        console.log(`location.handleMouseMove(${props.id}): drag distanceY ${distanceY}`)
        if (divRef && divRef.current) {
            if (Math.abs(distanceY) > divRef.current.clientHeight) {
                console.log(`lastMouseYRef.current ${lastMouseYRef.current} - e.offsetY ${e.offsetY} > divRef.current.clientHeight ${divRef.current.clientHeight} `)
                setLastMouseY(e.offsetY)
                lastMouseYRef.current = e.offsetY
                e.stopPropagation();
                const offset: number = distanceY > 0 ? 1 : -1
                console.log(`bink!! distanceY ${distanceY} dragItemIndex ${dragItemIndexRef.current} offset ${offset}`)
                props.onEdit(dragItemIndexRef.current, offset)
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        mouseDownRef.current = mouseDown
    }, [mouseDown])

    useEffect(() => {
        lastMouseYRef.current = lastMouseY
    }, [lastMouseY])

    useEffect(() => {
        dragItemIndexRef.current = dragItemIndex
    }, [dragItemIndex])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`init`)
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown)

        return () => {
            console.log(`shutdown`)
            window.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown)
            window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp)
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
            }
    }, [])

    return (
        // onMouseDownCapture={handleMouseDown} onMouseUpCapture={ handleMouseUp } onMouseMoveCapture={ handleMouseMove }
        <div className="location" ref={divRef}>
            <div className="location-item">{props.bars}.</div>
            <div className="location-item">{props.beats}.</div>
            <div className="location-item">{props.divisions}</div>
        </div>)
}
```

Comment: It looks like a DAW tray control - personal comment: I find mouse interaction imprecise and awful for setting locators, I would rather enhance the keyboard experience (up/down changes bar, holding shift changes beat, etc...) before getting crazy with mouse events as you can see!

Comment: This is for editing the length of the loop. I think it's a pretty good interface.

Comment: Plus I guess I will have the same issue with any other drag operation

Comment: In that case I highly recommend to rely on [something already existing](https://bokuweb.github.io/react-rnd/stories/?path=/story/grid--resize) ^^

Comment: Can somebody else answer?

Comment: [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-ardinghelli-phgboi?file=/src/App.js) is doing what you want then - you have to fine tune the sensibility of the intervals somehow, but it works on different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the solution on Reddit.

> React uses virtual dom, so don't attach listeners to the dom. Can you
> add onClick atribute to your component and log something in callback
> function? <div onClick={() => yourHandlerFunction()}> ...

Works great.